# How to test Android in-app purchases for different stores?

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, google-play, amazon-appstore, yandex

I've integrated the open-iab for unity: https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB-Unity-Plugin
into my app and setted up the SKU Mapping for Play Store, Yandex.Store and Amazon App Store.

Now when I start the app and try to make an in-app-purchase the Play Store pop-up is showing.
How can I test it for the other stores? I've installed all of them on my phone.

Thanks in advance.

Regards Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Market

Login to play store --> Sttings --> Account details
In account details you'll find LICENSE TESTING tab 
Add your testing accounts(xyz@gmail.com) below LICENSE TESTING

And while testing on device make sure that
you have logged in with the same test account on device 
OR
if you are logged in with multiple accounts 
then your primary account on device should be test account

*Note you cannot test InApp purchase with publisher account
you need another gmail account for testing

For Amazon

You need to build separate apk for amazon in which you need initialize with amazon

for example "OpenIabHelper.mapSku(SKU_PREMIUM, OpenIabHelper.NAME_AMAZON,"yourSKUname");"
and same for other store,

for testing amazon InApp purchase on device you need 
to install amazon's InApp test apk

For Yandex Store

I have no idea about Yandex Store,
but if you make another apk for Yandex store too may solve your problem

Comment: I've mapped all SKU's from the Stores in my one and only APK. Maybe that's the mistake I did. I thought that OpenIAB could detect where  the app was downloaded from. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @DennG OpenIAB is checking where the App was downloaded from. You can configure this behavior with the method `setStoreSearchStrategy` on the OptionBuilder, see [github](https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB/wiki/How-To-add-OpenIAB-to-an-app)

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is late, but maybe can help others.

You should be able to do this. Once its built as an APK, use

adb install -i store_name your_apk.apk

replacing "store_name" with one of com.yandex.store and com.amazon.venezia - this tells the app who you are saying installed the app.

Note that for Amazon you need to use the Amazon App Tester app (which is good) and download the json file for the IAP products from your Amazon dashboard.